# Remove the (mv-command) tag as all questions got edited to be tagged with (mv) instead

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are the tags **[mv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mv)** and **[mv-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mv-command)**.

**UPDATE:**

Please do *not* make **mv-command** a synonym of **mv**, but just delete it.

As suggested by @Braiam, I edited all 9 questions tagged with **mv-command** and removed the tag or replaced it with **mv**, if not already both tags were used.
Now (2015/04/19) the tag **mv-command** contains 0 questions.

I also edited the tag wiki of **mv-command** to

> **Please do NOT use this tag! Use "mv" instead! This tag is going to be deleted!**

which hopefully prevents new users to tag their questions with it while it is still around.

I also tried to improve the excerpt and tag wiki of **mv**.

---

**Original post:**

I request to make **mv-command** a synonym of **mv** as master tag, because both are about equal in size and significance, but **mv** would have the same "syntax" as **[cp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cp)** then, which is a very similar tag and command.

---

## mv

**Description:**

> Use `mv` command, to rename SOURCE file(s) and folder(s) to DESTINATION, or move SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.
>
> For full manual type in a terminal window: man mv

**Stats:**

- **size:** 11 questions
- **age:** created May 2014
- **top answerer**: [muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru) (2A, score 10)
- **top asker:** [efrem](https://askubuntu.com/users/354628/efrem) (1Q, score 5)

---

## mv-command

**Description:**

> `mv`-command stands for `move` and is used to either rename files and/or move files to directories.

**Stats:**

- **size:** 9 questions
- **age:** created April 2014
- **top answerer**: [Oli](https://askubuntu.com/users/449/oli) (1A, score 11)
- **top asker:** [MaxDL](https://askubuntu.com/users/183702/maxdl) (1Q, score 12)

Comment: Unless a mod comes by, I think it will happen soon. I have suggested, and now it needs 4 upvotes from users with score 5+ in that tag.

Comment: Dammit. Typo.. I *don't* think it will happen soon unless a mod comes by.

Comment: @muru I notified Seth in chat. No idea whether he will speed the process up or not though...

Comment: There are just 9/11 questions. Anyone with 2k can do it in a single minute.

Comment: @Braiam I don't really understand what you wanted to tell me...

Comment: @ByteCommander he's suggesting that you retag questions.

Comment: @muru Ah, thanks. I thought the 9/11 was supposed to have a special meaning. So I could just pick all "mv-command" questions and replace the tag with "mv" and that will automatically remove the "mv-command" tag?

Comment: @ByteCommander not immediately, but periodically they clean out unused tags.

Comment: I actually prefer mv-command rather than just mv, for the same reasons UL did.

Comment: @Braiam Too late...

Comment: No, actually it isn't, just 1 minute more.